# how to get data from selection tag with django

Tags: html, django, django-3.0

I trying to implement filter function to get data from a selection tag using post form but the result is always None

view.py

```
def filter(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
      title = request.POST.get('da',None)
      print(title)
      titre = Product.objects.filter(title=title)
      print(titre)
      return render(request, 'searchapp/searchview.html', {'qs': titre})

    else:
     return render(request,'searchapp/searchview.html',{'qs':products})
```

html :

```
div>
    <form action="{% url 'search:query' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Title</label>
                  <select title="da" class="form-control">
                        {% for obj in qs %}
                 <option value="{{obj}}">{{obj}}</option>
                         {%endfor%}
                         </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Add Product</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You did not specify a `name=`.

Comment: where should i specify the name  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of title attribute use name='da' in your select.

Comment: yes i did it and it works , my problem now  how to keep selected option after form submission ??